# Return object from arraylist with highest value?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, return

I'm trying to return an object from an arraylist I have, which contains
different opponents for my text-based fighting game. The opponents in the
arraylist have different "deadlylevels", to seperate one easy opponent from
a tough one.

To explain it differently; Let's say I have three opponents in my arraylist, and they have the deadlylevels of 30, 40 and 50, respectively. I want to return
the most deadliest of them, so that would be the opponent who has a deadlylevel of 50.

I have already given them different deadlylevels, but I'm not sure how
to return the opponent that has the highest deadlylevel.

Comment: [Sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) the `List` with a `Comparator` that uses the "deadlylevel" as criterion and get the first (or last) element.

Comment: @MickMnemonic
Thanks, I'll see if I can get it to work!

Comment: Paul's answer will do exactly what I suggested, but with less code, so you should probably choose that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `Comparator` that compares the levels of the oponents and use `Collections.max(oponentList , theComparator)`.

Answer (score 6):

If you wanted the maximum level, that would just be max(). But you want the max opponent, by level. In [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), we call that pattern `maxBy()`. If you can replace your `ArrayList` with `MutableList` then it becomes:

```
MutableList<Opponent> opponents = ...;
Opponent opponent = opponents.maxBy(Opponent::getDeadlyLevel);
```

If you can't or won't convert the `ArrayList`, you can still use static utility on `Iterate`.

```
Opponent opponent = Iterate.maxBy(opponents, Opponent::getDeadlyLevel);
```

You could use `Collections.max()` along with `Comparator.comparing()` to build the `Comparator`.

```
Opponent opponent =
    Collections.max(opponents, Comparator.comparing(Opponent::getDeadlyLevel));
```

Or you could use Java 8 Streams.

```
Optional<Opponent> optionalOpponent = 
    opponents.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Opponent::getDeadlyLevel));
Opponent opponent = optionalOpponent.get(); // If you're sure there's at least one
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Stream#max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) providing a function for the relevant attribute:

```
List<Fighter> list; // given a list of Fighters
Fighter deadliest = list.stream()
    .max((a,b) -> a.getDeadlyLevel() - b.getDeadlyLevel())
    .get();
```

Comment: The example doesn't compile.

Comment: @CraigP.Motlin oops - thumbing code on train (coded a Function not a BiFunction). Fixed now - thx.

Answer (score 1):

> Use Comparator.comparing

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;


public class DeathMatch {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        List<Opponent> list = Arrays.asList(new Opponent("ZZ",10),new Opponent("WW",50),new Opponent("MM", 30));
        Opponent deadliest = list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(p->p.getLevel())).get();
        System.out.println(deadliest.getName()+","+ deadliest.getLevel());
    }
}
```